# How do we decide if the PUSH/PULL socket should Bind() or Connect()?

Tags: c#, zeromq

While studying ZeroMQ the `PUSH` and `PULL` type of sockets did not make much sense to me. To my understanding a `PUSH` socket should always `.connect()`, as it sends and the `PULL` socket should `.bind()`, as it only receives the data.

The usual example shows something like this:

[image: PUSH-PULL example]
And here is how it is usually setup:

- Node A has **PUSH** socket and **binds** (why?)
- Node C has **PULL** socket and **binds**
- Middle nodes have **PULL** and **PUSH** sockets, but `.bind()` none, and
  `.connect()` both.

**How** do we decide if the PUSH/PULL socket should **`.bind()`** or be **`.connect()`**-ed?

Comment: I recommend reading the zeromq documentation, which explains the use of bind and connect.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the more stable parts of the system ("servers") will bind and the more transient parts (multiple "clients") will connect.

Most ZeroMQ sockets can bind (act as server) or connect (act as client).  And you can connect first and bind later.  The client will keep trying to connect until the server is up.  This is a very nice feature of ZeroMQ.

In case of PUSH/PULL it is fine for either to bind and either to connect.  This is also true for PUB/SUB, ROUTER/DEALER, etc.

In the diagram, you could add or remove middle nodes at run time without having to reconfigure or restart Nodes A or C.  That is probably why they chose to bind A and C.

Answer (score -1):

**Why?**  <sub>( .bind() and not .connect() )</sub> 
**Because** simply **Node-A** has zero knowledge, how many **Node-B** worker-type **`PULL`**-**`PUSH`** data-processors will appear / disappear in near or far future, the less it can know their respective addresses ( so it simply cannot guess when/where to `.connect()` to, from it's own side ).

---

**How?**  <sup>( to decide whether one shall .bind() or be .connect()-ed )</sup> 
In static-deterministic system design, one can freely choose. ZeroMQ framework does the rest. Smart, isn't it?

In dynamic-nondeterministic system design, one shall **`.bind()`** on those nodes, that have guarranteed "visibility" ( address, connectivity ), the rest of the mortals ought **`.connect()`** to those of the "light-houses", that remained yet visible to them in the fierce storms of the harsh reality :o)